# Tableau Calculated Date Dimension with Output Dependent Upon Field

Tags: date, tableau-api

My objective is to create one date dimension that users can use to filter the dashboard. There are two components to achieve this:

(1)
I have a field "Type". Depending on what "Type" something is, a different date is considered relevant. For example, if Type = "A" then I need to use the "Sales Date"; however, if Type = "B" then I need to use the "Close Date".

(2)
Type C is unique. If Type = "C" then I need it to filter on records EITHER where a field "Yr. Credited" equals the year the user selected with the newly created date dimension OR "Closed Date". To clarify, both "Yr. Credited" AND "Closed Date" are relevant to Type C. The desired result is that one or both of these two fields will fall into the user-selected date range.

Happy to clarify if anything remains fuzzy.

Comment: For your first question, are you filtering on Type?

Comment: First question is resolved: Just required a simply if then statement.
If Type = A then "Closed Date
"

Comment: You can do it with another if. How does the user select the year? And what is the result, ie. The value to display, for C if 0, 1, 2 fields are in that year

Comment: The user should be able to select the year using the quick filter, which will be based off of this newly created calculated field. The objective is for this calculated field to function as a filter so I'm not sure I understand your second question--please clarify.

Comment: @sqlbg You say that if cat = C, there are two data field considered. But what do you do if one date field is 2014 and the other 2015. Which date should be used to filter on? So say I select 2014 as my filter year, what is your expected output if only "Yr. Credited" is in 2014, if only "Close Date" is in 2014 and if BOTH are in 2014?